# sqlcmd syntax error at line 

Tags: sql-server-2008

I used SQL server 2008 script wizard to create a script that would recreate a database and all its components on a remote server with sql server 2005. 
Executing it from sqlcmd since its over 8gigs large it ran well until it gave the following error:

sqlcmd syntax error at line 40875 at ')'

I cannot open the script file to check it since its so large and checked the sql server management studio and all tables were created except one and none of the triggers, functions etc were created.
Do I need to recreate a script for each of these that were not transferred and why are there syntax errors if sql creates the script itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignore the question...i mean I am just scripting what I need but I was just curious as to why the wizard generates errors.